# Connecting flight through Dubai with an Israeli/Jewish name

Tags: transit, dual-nationality, dxb

I'm planning to travel from the UK to NZ in early 2015. The cheapest flights (Qantas) have a connection via Dubai.

I have more than one citizenship, so I can avoid using an Israeli passport (phew), but I'm still concerned that I might be stopped at some point due to my surname, "Yehudi", which literally translates to "Jew" in both Hebrew and Arabic. I'm not a religious Jew, but that's pretty much beside the point I should imagine.

Does anyone else with a markedly Jewish name have experience passing through Dubai, or does anyone know of cases when it may have been done safely?

Comment: Entering with that passport is a problem, having that name is not a problem, anyway being in the airside is fine.

Comment: Do you have any reference sources or personal experience to back that up?

Comment: No, if I did I would be posting an answer.. but I know as everyone else that Dubai is very open when it comes to transiting via it, but not so when it comes to entering it. They have a reputation to keep when it comes to their airport as the true connection between the east and west..

Comment: Anyway, I did a quick search and I found no results where people with similar situations like yours were denied to _transit_. If something like that happened it would have been posted somewhere. Anyway, entering Dubai is NOT allowed for people holding your nationality or were born there. For more details see [this page](http://www.dubaifaqs.com/israeli-stamp-passport-dubai.php)

Comment: @yochannah does your place of birth say "Israel" or "NZ"?

Comment: I'm not born in Israel, thankfully...

Answer (score 8):

You're not going to get any references to back this up, because no official source in the UAE is *ever* going to say "We love Jews! Please transit!" or "We hate Jewish-sounding people, regardless of their actual religion or their passports!".

That said, despite public huffing and puffing, [the UAE's morals are famously flexible when it comes to making money](http://www.jpost.com/Middle-East/Israelis-doing-business-in-Dubai-will-wait-out-storm), which is why [Israeli passport holders are allowed to transit through the UAE](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/39042/can-you-transit-through-dubai-airport-when-holding-an-israeli-passport/39043#39043) (although they refuse to put this in writing either), and so are [people with Israeli-stamped passports](http://www.dubaifaqs.com/israeli-stamp-passport-dubai.php), who can enter the UAE as well.  So if all you're going to do is transit through the UAE, without going through immigration, and you have a valid passport with a Jewish-sounding name, I am quite sure **you will not have the slightest problem**.

Comment: Business is business, both parties (arabs and jews) are fine when it comes to business, they put all political issues aside.. once business is done, it is time to go live on TV again and repeat the same old phrases...