# Can you transit through Dubai airport when holding an Israeli passport?

Tags: dxb, israeli-citizens

Is it possible for an Israeli passport holder to transit through Dubai airport? Obviously assuming that the person stays air-side, has a connection on the same ticket, and the next flight leaves within the same day.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I through check my bags on separate bookings (international flights)?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/2173/can-i-through-check-my-bags-on-separate-bookings-international-flights)

Comment: It's different because the person in question has a second passport which he can show to the immigration authorities.

Comment: @Gagravarr this question is not about bags. UAE bans all Israeli passport holders from entering the country and has no diplomatic relations with Israel.

Comment: @pnuts Jewish name and Israeli passport are entirely different things :)

Comment: @pnuts Unanswered questions cannot be duplicates.

Comment: But the answer on that Q links to this Q! Argh, inception!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regrettably, the United Arab Emirates [refuses to make a clear statement on this](http://www.jewishnews.net.au/uae-must-make-direct-statement-on-transits/28809), probably out of fear at the Arab backlash at dealing with the Zionist entity and all that.

However, **in practice**, transiting Dubai (or any other UAE airport) with an Israeli passport seems fine.  The CEO of Australian airline Qantas, which has a close partnership with Emirates, has [publicly stated](http://www.haaretz.com/jewish-world/jewish-world-features/australian-jews-seek-reassurance-on-qantas-emirates-deal.premium-1.477375):

> “Passengers do not need to pass through immigration at Dubai to
>   continue onward to Europe,” he wrote. “**Israeli passport holders can
>   transit through Dubai.”**

Actually *entering* the UAE, though, is generally not allowed, certainly not without an advance visa which is rarely granted.