# Transit for Israeli passport holders in Abu Dhabi

Tags: transit, uae, abu-dhabi, israeli-citizens

Could I have a problem boarding an Alitalia and Etihad Airways flight with an Israeli passport if I pass through Abu Dhabi airport?

Comment: I know people who did this in Dubai, without problem.

Answer (score 2):

You will have no problems as there are no passport checks during transit in Abu Dhabi.

As long as your flight boards you, you are fine.

Comment: *As long as your flight boards you* is the main concern. Based on [a similar question about Dubai](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/39042/52465) there should be no problem with this too.